# Why specflow is needed in cucumber even its supporting BDD Tools

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow

I am trying to find why specflow is needed for developing BDD test automation framework using .NET. As Cucumber itself is a BDD Tool, why cant we use Cucumber directly in .NET projects?

Comment: Please edit for proper grammar. Beside that, if you could read [ask] and then clarify exactly what you mean by "specflow is needed in cucumber", what you expected, and how that differs from what you expected, that would go a long way to helping others to understand your question.

Answer (score 15):

[Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) is an application that reads Gherkin syntax plain text specification files and runs ruby files to execute those specifications.

Specflow is a 'port' of cucumber for .net that also uses Gherkin syntax files but wires them up to .net code. If you look at the [cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs) it states that to use cucumber in .net you do it via SpecFlow.

I don't think you can run cucumber in .net unless you are thinking of using iron ruby...

Answer (score 7):

Cucumber is written primarily for Ruby projects, and executes in Ruby.

Ports exist for other languages. Cucumber-JVM executes in Java, and SpecFlow executes in .NET. If you want to write your test framework in .NET, SpecFlow is what you should use.

If you're writing acceptance tests (which is what Cucumber is really designed for), there's no reason why your framework has to be in the same language that your developers write in. Your framework should be in a separate repo to your application, and deploy independently. You can test a PHP website using a ruby framework, a Rails website using a Cucumber-JVM framework.. it doesn't matter so long as your deployment process can handle it and you are competent in the language.

Comment: I've done BDD in PHP via Behat. We heavily customized our own Gerkin commands. A few hundred lines of PHP to produce custom When/Then commands. If we used a non-php or non-javascript Gherkin tool., we'd have introduced another language into our build chain.

Comment: Yeah. I think my point was more just it doesn't *have* to be. But I generally advise people stick to the same language.

Comment: Agreed. For frontend tests, it does _not_ have to be. I prefer Java due to the wide range of available mature libraries, tutorials, and tooling for absolutely free. Highly likely that whatever custom thing you wrote in say, PHP, was already done in one of the 14M available libraries from the Maven Repo.